# FILE descriptors and select on linux fifos

Tags: c++, c, linux, file

I have a class wrapper for FILE* `(see GetHandle() == FILE*)`..

I wanted to implement a function questioning for `hasData`:

```
bool File::hasData(int waitSecs) {
    fd_set set;
    struct timeval tv;
    FD_ZERO(&set);
    FD_SET(fileno( GetHandle() ), &set);
    tv.tv_sec = waitSecs;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;
    int res = select(fileno( GetHandle())+1, &set, NULL, NULL, &tv);
    return res > 0;
}
```

it turns out of that the FILE* has it's inner buffer(duh), and so unless I read ALL the data, `select` would return 0 until I do, therefore I found two ugly ways, one I can query if the `read ptr != write ptr` inside the FILE* handle, and I can call `setbuf` with the NULL as buffer so there will not be any internal buffering and so any read would read exactly the amount requested and select would return a positive number...

The question is.. is there a more elegant way to implement such a function given a FILE* and unmanaged reads and writes?

Comment: Did you try to use `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING`?

Comment: The other pitfall of this approach is using `select()` which is limited in support of file descriptors w/ numbers higher than some hardcoded limit (about `1024`), so in application w/ many opened file descriptors (which are not only wasted for `FILE*`, but as well for socket connections) this code will not be able to use `FD_SET` properly.

Comment: actually select returns -1 if error occurs, 0 if timeout occurs, and the fileno value if (read) has some data to read (or write has completed writing, etc) Not necessarily some number greater than 1024.

Comment: as written, this function waits for either: 1) the timeout to occur 2) the indicated input (not necessarily a file, could be a socket, etc) to have data available to read.

Comment: zaufi currently those are not of any concern.. user36..but it won't have any input, so it will always time out.. as the FILE* buffered it, BatuhanTasdoven, same as setbuf with null..